# How to package a Jar for OSX?

Tags: macos, ant, jar

I know JarBundler is nolonger developed and doesn't work with 1.7 ([link](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/)) and from the same site I found [AppBundler](https://java.net/downloads/appbundler/appbundler.html) which does produce proper `.app` files from jars.

I found [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=550811) that the contents of these jar-apps are the same, so I did as the person suggested and only replaced the jar file inside `Contents/Java` (or `Contents/Resources/Java` in the old Jar Bundler), and it works. I could keep using AppBundler, but I'd prefer not needing an extra dependency/plugin for Ant.

Anyways, when I automate it with Ant - the `.app` doesn't open. I narrowed it down to this:

- A `.app` produced from AppBundler
- If I copy and paste it somewhere else, it launches
- If I copy and paste it with Ant, it doesn't launch

I even tried things like [clearing my application state cache](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1357539), without luck. Again, the weird thing is if I copy the "source app" myself, the copy launches. If I copy the source app with Ant (and I'm doing nothing else) it doesn't.

Here's my Ant snippet (`.app` are just folders AFAIK) (`dist.macapp` is the name of the `.app`):

```
<copy todir="${dist.dir}" >  
    <fileset dir="${resources.dir}">  
        <include name="${dist.macapp}/**" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

---

I guess I have two questions:

1. Why isn't this working (I think I provided enough what have I tried :P )
2. Is there a better way to do this (Java Web Start is out of the question, maybe something I'll look into later)

Answer (score 1):

A .app file on Mac is just a standardized folder layout. You could always bundle it yourself with a script. Simply replacing the jar file isn't quite enough.

Make something like this

```
Contents/
    Java/yourjar.jar
    info.plist /* specific to your application! maybe make a template then find and replace strings */
    MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
```

Copy the executable `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub` into the `MacOS` folder (this is not app specific and could be done once).

I am not sure of the format for the info.plist specific to Java.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I'm trying that but it doesn't launch if I copy it using Ant (but it does if I do it manually).

Comment: As for "replacing the jar", I'm not sure what you mean that isn't quite enough. To clarify, I already generated an application-specific `info.plist`. And **the only thing I'm doing is copy and pasting**, and it works manually but not with Ant (that's the first problem I need to solve)

Comment: @Raekye Replacing the yourjar.jar in my example. What about the MacOS folder, does that have a JavaApplicationStub or equivalent script?

Comment: Yes. As I said, it's a complete `.app`, it works by itself, it works when I copy and paste it, but when I copy it with Ant it stops launching (I want to have the application stub in a separate folder and whenever I build copy it and update the jar inside)